# Using robot_state_publisher with a .sdf file

Tags: gazebo, urdf, sdf, ros-groovy, robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the documentation of robot_state_publisher, it appears that the package is really only compatible with the .urdf format.  Could it work with .sdf?

If not, what would be the recommended way to create the /tf data from an .sdf model loaded in Gazebo?

My initial thoughts are to grab data from the /gazebo/link_states topic and work it into the tf format ala something like the [Writing a tf broadcaster (C++)](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29) tutorial.  Running this on Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS Groovy.  I appreciate any insights.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61097/using-robot_state_publisher-with-a-.sdf-file/) by [pyrobat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3219/pyrobat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-04-18

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alf](https://answers.ros.org/users/23797/alf/) on 2016-01-14**:
This is a newer post with the same issue: http://answers.ros.org/question/204803/robot_state_publisher-with-sdf-files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the best solution for this problem would to add SDF support to [kdl_parser](http://www.ros.org/wiki/kdl_parser). Slightly more challenging would be to add SDF support to rviz display plugin to visualize the robot.

An easier solution right now would be to maintain 2 copies of your robot (SDF and URDF), or use Gazebo's URDF parser (which lags a bit behind the SDF).

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2013-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1